# Form_Load not being triggered

Tags: vb6

My clients are running into this strange issue where a form sometimes not loads correctly. I have identified this as a problem where the `Form_Load` event is not being triggered. Since the problem is impossible to reproduce I cannot debug this. I was hoping someone has run into the same problem and solved this.

The form is being loaded as a global. I do not create a variable to start a new instance. I just open the form like this:

```
frmProduct.ProductID = 548
frmProduct.show 1
```

Then, when the form needs to close I run `Unload Me` inside the form itself. This seems to work since the form closes. But sometimes when the form is being loaded again it does not trigger the Load event. My guess is that while I unload the form it remains in memory and when the `frmProduct.show` is being run the form just becomes visible again without actually being loaded. I hacked a workaround form some forms by unloading them before loading them to make sure the Load event would trigger. But that is an ugly solution that I would like to avoid.

Can anyone verify that my theory is correct that forms sometimes remain in memory while they should have been closed? And if this is really the case, how to close them properly?

Comment: Create a form instance and do not use the global instance.

Comment: @Steve That would be an idea but the project has dozens of forms including references to each other. It would take allot of time to change this design. That's why I asked for a different solution.

Comment: If some other part of your program tries to access a variable on a form that you've unloaded, such as 'frmProduct.ProductID' in your example for instance, the form may be loaded again although it won't be made visible.

Comment: @JohnEason Isn't that only the case when a control is accessed? To my knowing, this isn't the case with public form variables or properties which don't access controls.

Comment: As far as I can remember from distant memory **any** access to an unloaded form will cause it to be loaded, including public form variables.

Comment: Did you try to use the activate event instead?

Comment: @nabuchodonossor I did not because I need to use the Load event.

Comment: So I´m afraid you have either have to follow @Steve ´s hint or you close it instead of unload, and load it again.

Comment: I see now that this question is marked with the VB6 tag. VB.NET and VB6 while something similar are built on a very different base. So, are you using VB6 or VB.NET?

Comment: @Steve it has been tagged VB6 since it was created, I believe. I just checked the edit history.

Comment: @steve This is a VB6 problem. The tag is correct.